# Conan install fails: 'compiler not defined for compiler.libcxx'

Tags: cmake, installation, conan

Conan install fails with the message below. As I could follow, it is an issue since about 2018.
I did follow some discussions, about changing configurations, defaults, profiles,
promising discussion in the afternoon, etc., but did not see a solution that works.
Is there any way I can use in my cmake file to fix it, or to downgrade to a stable version?
I have chosen Conan because in this way my users can simply install my app. 
They do not want to bother (and even: they cannot)  with maybe it works, or try this or that.
Also myself could not install on my laptop, only on my desktop.
Both of them are Ubuntu 18.04, generated from the same DVD, using defaults.

```
ERROR: compiler not defined for compiler.libcxx
Please define compiler value first too
CMake Error at cmake/Conan.cmake:41 (message):
  conan install command failed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:48 (setup_conan)
```

Comment: The place for getting support is https://github.com/conan-io/cmake-conan/issues. Also. you need to share more details, like your conan profile, your cmake file, conan version and cmake-conan version ...

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove `~/.conan/data/<your_library>`. It helped me.

Comment: Better use `conan remove -f <your_library>` instead then.